# 'Let's Encrypt' SSL installed on Godaddy hosting but still showing insecure (dangerous)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

I've created and installed a 'Let's Encrypt' SSL certificate for our domain on a Godaddy (Ultimate Linux Hosting with cPanel) hosting. The domain is: `adamandalice.com`. I've checked on https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html, and it shows the SSL is installed correctly. My website is created in wordpress.

After installing the SSL certificate successfully, the website still shows as insecure (dangerous). I've deleted cache, closed browser, even restarted my computer. But still getting insecure (dangerous) status on the browser.

I've checked the `.htaccess` file on the root of the website file directory, and tried adding many different suggestions of `.htaccess` script from different forums. None of them worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://adamandalice.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^adamandalice\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.adamandalice\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ipg
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The weird thing is, the website appears as secure with the padlock on the following:

- on Chrome on my iPhone.
- on Microsoft Edge browser on my Windows 10 laptop.

However, it appears as NOT secure (dangerous) on the following:

- on Chrome on my Windows 10 laptop.
- on Chrome on my Macbook pro.
- on Safari on my Macbook pro.
- When I called Godaddy support, they also confirmed that they can see the site as insecure (dangerous). They couldn't provide much of an assistance, as they said the ssl certificate is a 3rd party one, and that I need to check with the certificate provider.

Comment: _“The domain is: adamandalice.com”_ - trying to visit that in Chrome, gets me a warning that this might be a _phishing_ site. And even if I ignore that and try to proceed, our Trend Micro still blocks it as a dangerous site. Is _that_ what you are talking about? If so, that does not have much to do with SSL in the first place.

Comment: If you are not talking about the malware warning, but just the site being marked as “insecure” in terms of proper HTTPS implementation - then that is likely due to external resources, that you are still embedding via HTTP. Go check the browser console then, it should tell you who the offenders are.

Comment: Thank you for your response and notifying me on this. I wasn't aware the website has potential malicious files or malware. So the problem seems to be more than just an SSL cert then!! Could you advise on a security plugin or software, or a way to scan all my Wordpress files and clear any infection, that is ideally free, or altenatively won't cost me a fortune. The reason I didn't want to go with Godaddy's solution is because it's a rip off, as with the rest of their offers.

Comment: I'm looking to move to HostGator, because they're more small business and individuals friendly hosting provider, whereas Godaddy is very pricey. But before I move, I'm guessing I will need to ensure my website is secure and there are no infections. Or can I move to HostGator and then purchase a Website security solution from them to then start scanning my website for malware (after moving to HostGator)?

Comment: What's the best approach here?